# How to minimize latency in Tor?

Tags: configuration

I am looking for a way to minimize the latency while using Tor, while remaining relatively anonymous. A minor loss in anonymity is acceptable, however.

This is mostly for testing purposes, but I would still like to try.

Is there a way to do this, i.e. cut down the latency as much as possible?

Reconfigure torrc to use only very fast relays?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: Latency is not the same as speed. Even if you only used fast relays, there would still be latency between the relays.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are building out a collector process that needs to get through Tor as fast as possible. Good luck to you!

There is a way:

Run your own relays and force by way of your torrc file to connect to your own relays. Set your relay bandwidth limits to be very high and set it to not publish that they exist to the larger Tor community.

This of course is not very secure at all and assumes that you even get accepted by Tor to receive the exit relay flag and the guard node flag.

This also kind of takes a crap on the Tor community by not letting anyone else use your fast relays.

But, to each their own! Do what thou wilt shall be the whole of the law. And also unfortunately, the wise one said "karma is a bitch."